# Removing lock on non-graceful application shutdown

Tags: java, xodus

Related to this question: [Remove lock on environment at every transaction end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012463/remove-lock-on-environment-at-every-transaction-end) and [How does Jetbrains YouTrack server scales over load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211112/how-does-jetbrains-youtrack-server-scales-over-load/63757843#63757843)

What can be done to implement a way for Xodus Lock Mechanism to work even with non-graceful application shutdown? For instance, if the application process (which opened write access to a Xodus environment) is `kill`ed, the lock remains and the new application process cannot write to the database anymore due to the `.lck` file, so a manual `find . -name "xd.lck" -type f -delete` needs to be executed to make it work again.

Additionally, this is true also with multi-process servlet containers/servers which spawns multiple processes of the same application. So the question, **how can Xodus Locking mechanism play well with these scenarios?**

Answer (score 1):

The lock is immediately released after "the application process (which opened write access to a Xodus environment) is killed".

Comment: How do you share an Environment object across different processes btw?

Comment: This is not the case for Nginx Unit, as soon as you reconfigurate the web application server with the new war with: `curl -X PUT -d@start.json '127.0.0.1:8443/config/'` then this new configured app will get the lock error `nginx.unit.Context.service(Context.java:971)
        at jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.tryLock(Log.kt:799)
        at jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.<init>(Log.kt:120)`

Comment: Here's a gist to explain what I mean: https://gist.github.com/cyberquarks/51ac2a71aafc874459d1fc9fb5137495

Comment: Also, I filed and issue related to this, here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-815