# Solution to remove lock after Application server redeployment

Tags: java, glassfish, xodus

Before redeploying the application war, I checked the xd.lck file from one of the environment path:

```
Private property of Exodus: 20578@localhost

jetbrains.exodus.io.LockingManager.lock(LockingManager.kt:89)
```

I'm testing from both Nginx Unit and Payara server to eliminate the possibility that this is an isolated case with Unit.

And process `20578` shows from *htop*:

```
20578 root       20   0 2868M  748M  7152 S  0.7 75.8 14:05.75 /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64/bin/java -cp /
```

After redeployment finished successfully, accessing the web application throws:

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.tryLock(Log.kt:799)
    at jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.<init>(Log.kt:120)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:142)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:121)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:10
```

And checking the same `xd.lck` file shows the same content. Meaning to say that "lock is not immediately released" contrary to what is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786000/removing-lock-on-non-graceful-application-shutdown).

My assumption is for this specific case with Payara Server (based on Glassfish) is that, the server does not kill the previous process even after redeployment has completed. Maybe perhaps for "zero-downtime" redeployment, not sure, Payara experts can correct me here.

*Checking with htop the process `20578` is still running even after the redeployment.*

As with Xodus, since most application servers behave this way, **what would be the best solution and/or workaround so we don't need to manually delete all lock files of each environment (if can be deleted) every time we redeploy?**

Comment: If the lock file won't delete, what is done is to kill the process, other options we do is to totally stop the server (downtime) the up it again which is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is for the Java application to look for the process locking the file then do a `kill -15` signal for example to gracefully make the Java handle the signal to be able to close environments:

```java
// Get all PersistentEntityStore's
entityStoreMap.forEach((dir, entityStore) -> {
   entityStore.getEnvironment().close();
   entityStore.close();
}
```